# Bearer error="invalid_token", error_description="The signature is invalid"

Tags: .net-core, azure-active-directory, asp.net-core-2.0, asp.net-core-webapi

I have a angular application that request a token from azure. The login went well and I get a token. This token is now send from the angular app to a net core webapi application. Net core should verify this token but failed. I think the webapi should also contact azure to validate the token because it has no knowledge of the private and public key that is needed to verify the token.

At the moment it is not clear why it is failing. Both angular app and the webapi are running local on my computer.

The error is: `Microsoft.IdentityModel.Tokens.SecurityTokenInvalidSignatureException: 'IDX10500: Signature validation failed. No security keys were provided to validate the signature.'`

my net core 2 config is:

```
var tokenValidationParameters = new TokenValidationParameters
            {

                RequireExpirationTime = true,
                RequireSignedTokens = false,
                ValidateIssuerSigningKey = true,
                ValidateIssuer = true,
                ValidIssuer = "8d708afe-2966-40b7-918c-a39551625958",
                ValidateAudience = true,
                ValidAudience = "https://sts.windows.net/a1d50521-9687-4e4d-a76d-ddd53ab0c668/",
                ValidateLifetime = false,
                ClockSkew = TimeSpan.Zero
            };
            services.AddAuthentication(options =>
            {
                options.DefaultScheme = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;

            }).AddJwtBearer(options =>
            {

                options.Audience = "8d708afe-2966-40b7-918c-a39551625958";
                options.ClaimsIssuer = "https://sts.windows.net/a1d50521-9687-4e4d-a76d-ddd53ab0c668/";
                options.RequireHttpsMetadata=false;
                options.TokenValidationParameters = tokenValidationParameters;
                options.SaveToken = true;
            });
```

Comment: can you please share the fix

Comment: For new visitors [try this link](https://github.com/aspnet/Home/issues/2193#issuecomment-384859564)

Answer (score 19):

That is quite a lot of configuration you have :)

The two mandatory settings are the Audience and Authority:

```
services
    .AddAuthentication(JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)
    .AddJwtBearer(o =>
    {
        o.Audience = "8d708afe-2966-40b7-918c-a39551625958";
        o.Authority = "https://login.microsoftonline.com/a1d50521-9687-4e4d-a76d-ddd53ab0c668/";
    });
```

You are missing the Authority so it does not know where to load the signing public keys from.

Comment: Could you create a new question with details on what you have done?

Comment: [this link] {https://github.com/aspnet/Home/issues/2193#issuecomment-384859564} solved the problem. I was issuing a token but when it came back for validation Invalid token error popped up and the API responded 401

Comment: Ahh you have multiple schemes :)

Comment: No, I have just one JWT authorization

Comment: you can also use TokenValidationParameters.ValidAudiences to add additional audience url. For example, when the caller uses identifierUris as scope to request the token, the default audience check will be failed because the audience is the App Id of the App.
```c#
options.TokenValidationParameters.ValidAudiences = new string[]
                    {
                            "[identifierUris]"
                    };
```

Comment: Similar "checklist" style follow-on: And then make sure `Configure` in Startup.cs is up to date as well. I had my `ConfigureServices` right, but was getting this error b/c I'd brain farted adding (ie, I hadn't added) `app.UseAuthentication();` in `Configure`. 

Comment: you are savior. I was getting 401 errors. I was passing Authority URL wrong. It's working for me great now.

Comment: "You are missing the Authority so it does not know where to load the signing public keys from." -> This!

Answer (score -1):

You are missing `IssuerSigningKey` property in your **TokenValidationParameters**. Thats why its complaining.

The simplest example would be

```
IssuerSigningKey = new SymmetricSecurityKey(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes("yOURsECRETkEY12345"))
```

I'm not sure how azure comes into play, you probably need it to retrieve security key information, if thats your signing authority

**Edit:**

Azure specific settings

```
.AddJwtBearer(options => {
        options.Authority = string.Format("https://login.microsoftonline.com/tfp/{0}/{1}/v2.0/", Configuration["Authentication:AzureAd:Tenant"], Configuration["Authentication:AzureAd:Policy"]);
        options.Audience = Configuration["Authentication:AzureAd:ClientId"];
    });
```

Comment: Based on the question, OP is not using the AAD B2C, for which your answer applies. For the above part, AAD does not use symmetric keys, they use asymmetric keys. And you should not be hard-coding them anyway.

Comment: @juunas Thus the qualification **simplest example**

Comment: It's a lot simpler to mention the authority and have it auto-load the right signing keys by itself in my opinion.

Comment: @juunas Agreed.